# Feature Request: can embed `svg` vector graphics from wikipedia

Tags: feature-request, markdown

Many image files on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science) are vector graphic files.

That is, they are not `JPEG`s or `PNG`s.

A `JPEG` is like a sheet of graph paper where each square is filled in with just one color.

vector graphics, such as files whose names end in `.svg` trace nice smooth lines.

the computer science educators stack exchange need not host (store copies) of the files directly. Wikipedia already hosts the files, I just want to embed them.

---

## Markdown Language

```
![a cactus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cactus_graph#/media/File:Cactus_graph.svg)
```

---

## HTML

Stack exchange does allow a little bit of HTML, including anchor tags `<a>...<\a>`. However, it works for grids of colored squares (pixel grids), not vector graphics.

```
<a href="www.google.com"> <img src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cactus_graph#/media/File:Cactus_graph.svg" width="100" height="132">
</a>
```

[image]

Comment: I think that you'd probably get a better answer from [meta.se] since this is a general question about the Stack Exchange sites, but it looks to me like a browser issue. The markdown engine successfully spits out an `<img>` element, but the image doesn't actually render (at least on my machine).